# CKEditor 4 - how to add font family and font size controls to the toolbar

Tags: ckeditor

I have a config.toolbarGroups setting in config.js but I don't know what name to use for the groups to add font family/font size controls. (It seems the documentation is lacking in this regard). I've found some suggestion that I should use CKBuilder to create a package that already includes it, but I can't redeploy the entire ckeditor just to add a couple of buttons.

Edit: My CKEditor is version 4

Any advise?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you've got the *Full Package* version of ckeditor. I'd originally had the *Standard Package* and had similar problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two (mutually exclusive) ways to configure the toolbar.  Check out the following:

http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/plugins/toolbar/toolbar.html

I tried to use config.toolbarGroups first, but ended up using config.toolbar instead.  Here's what I ended up using:

```
config.toolbar = [
                { name: 'save', items: [ 'savebtn','Undo','Redo' ] },
                { name: 'clipboard', items: [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord'] },
                { name: 'document', items: [ 'Find','Replace'] },
                '/',
                { name: 'lists', items: [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','Outdent','Indent'] },
                { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image','Table','Smiley','SpecialChar'] },
                { name: 'link', items: ['Link','Unlink'] },
                '/',
                { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Font','FontSize','Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript'] },
                //'/',
                { name: 'align', items: [ 'JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'] }
        ];
```

Note that I am using a save plugin that was generously contributed by kasper Taeymans, which can be found at the following location:

[How to add an ajax save button with loading gif to CKeditor 4.2.1. [Working Sample Plugin]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956257/how-to-add-an-ajax-save-button-with-loading-gif-to-ckeditor-4-2-1-sample-plugi)

I also found the following document to be really useful, even though it related to version 3:

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar

I used the information in this article to produce my configuration (I'm using version 4.2.1), specifically the names of the items (e.g. Cut, Copy, Paste), as this was the missing link in my case.

Answer (score 14):

```
config.extraPlugins = 'font';
```

You have to add the plugin...

Comment: I wasted 2 hours to figure this out! Thanks

Comment: Finally found what I was missing. Thanks.

Comment: And if you don't have the addon, you can get it from https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/font

Comment: And if you an existing one it's comma separated `config.extraPlugins = 'anotherplugin,font';`

Answer (score 1):

Took me a long time to figure out that I explicitly had to add `FontSize` to the toolbar, too - doesn't seem to work with `Font` only.

Comment: Why downvote? Downvoting without reasons isn't helpful. There wasn't much in the docs (at least in 2k14 - dunno if it got better).

Answer (score 0):

This can be used to add font family and font size in the CkEditor.

This is to be done in config.js.

Also see [docs](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar)

```
    config.font_names = 'Arial;Times New Roman;Verdana;' +  CKEDITOR.config.font_names;

config.toolbar_Full =
[
     { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ] },

    { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','CreateDiv','-',
                'JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl' ] }    

];

config.toolbar = 'Full';
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I'm using CKEditor v4. Also I specifically want to know what I need to add to config.toolbarGroups.

Comment: font size (with values) fr ckeditor 4 is here http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-toolbarGroups

Answer (score 0):

Add directly using script :

```
CKEDITOR.replace('content', {
      extraPlugins: 'uicolor,colorbutton,colordialog,font',
});
```

To change default styles of text :

```
CKEDITOR.addCss(".cke_editable{cursor:text; font-size: 25px; color: #FFFFFF;background-color: #006991;}");
```